# MySQL group field with their values

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume that I have a table call client.
In this table I have 3 fields (A, B, C)
I would like to group each rows when values of A = B  = C
ex:

```
A   B   C    otherRow
1   2   3    x 
2   1        x 
4   2        y
```

I would like to get  the folowing

```
(A,B,C)   otherRow  Count
    1     x         2
    2     x         2
    2     y         1
    3     x         1
    4     y         1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is `UNION`, not `JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
  `A,B,C`, 
  otherRow, 
  COUNT(`A,B,C`) AS `Count`
FROM
  (SELECT a AS `A,B,C`, otherRow FROM t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT b AS `A,B,C`, otherRow FROM t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c AS `A,B,C`, otherRow FROM t) AS u
GROUP BY
  `A,B,C`,
  otherRow
HAVING
  `A,B,C` IS NOT NULL
```

check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7539e/4). I've added `NULL`-check since it's not obvious what are your "empty" values. If you'll remove it, you'll get zero-count NULL-rows.